# How to determine optimal page size for DynamoDB scan/query?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In this [DynamoDB query/scan best practices guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html), I'm reading you can help avoid sudden spikes in read activity by reducing the page size of your query/scan (from the default max 1MB).

I have a few instances where I need to scan the entire table, and I'm using `paginateScan` to loop through and get all the items—something like this:

```js
async function fetchAll() {

  const pagedScan = paginateScan({
    client: ddbDocClient,
    pageSize: 100
  }, {
    TableName: 'tickets'
  });

  const results = [];

  for await (const page of pagedScan) {
    results.push(page.Items)
  }

  return results;

}
```

But not understanding if there are any tradeoffs in having the `pageSize` set lower or kept at the max 1MB.

Does setting a lower page size just make the query/scan take longer, so the read is spread out over a longer period of time? For instance, if I need to scan an entire table and don't care if it takes a while, should I set the page size to 1 item?

Does it matter at all if I'm ultimately just looping through to get all the items?

Comment: If you ask this question, you might not use the correct data store for your system. DynamoDB is designed for LOOKUP that should retrieve a single or a few records in each call. It can allow SCAN, however, it is not optimized for it. Consider replicating the data to S3 and Scan using Athena.

Comment: @Guy You are not wrong. Going to be migrating to a relational db setup, but need a shorter-term fix in the meantime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page size has both an impact on latency and performance.

##### Latency

A lower page size will obviously have to make more round trips to DynamoDB, which increases the latency of the Scan.

##### Cost

Having a lower page size will actually increase the cost somewhat, as each page is rounded up to the nearest 4KB. So a Scan with a page size of 1, would cost you 1 RCU for each item, whereas in reality you could probably fit 10's of items into a 4KB limit.

##### Why reduce it

Reducing the page size can be helpful if it's a background process and you don't want to consume all the capacity from the table impacting it's normal traffic. A lower page size will spread the reads out over a longer time and reduce how much capacity is consumed on a per second basis. This could also save costs if using provisioned mode, but it's a trade off between that and my aforementioned point on rounding up to 4KB.